# How to convert Octal Fraction to Decimal?

Tags: java, fractions, octal

For examle 10.5 should return 8.625 in Decimal. I've found examples on converting decimal fraction to octal, but not vise versa.

Use of inbuilt functions are okay.

These should help:

- [Converting octal fraction to decimal fraction:
  Maths](http://www.schoolelectronic.com/2012/01/convert-octal-fraction-to-decimal.html)
- [Online number conversion tool](http://coderstoolbox.net/number/)

Comment: Converting octal into double is the same as converting decimal into a double except you multiply/divide by 8 instead of 10.  I suggest you try doing it for decimal first and then doing it for octal should be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links. You should follow them too and show us where you get stuck.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not sure what you mean by 'converting decimal into a double'. Could you please link me to an reference?

Comment: Java doesn't have a `Decimal` type but it does have a `double` type.  This is what Java treats `8.625` as.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is

- check for `-` at the start and remember this for later.
- convert the number into a `long` as if the `.` wasn't there.
- remember where the `.` was and at the end divide by 8^(n) where n is the number of decimal places.  You can do this with `>>` instead. Or even better use `Math.scaleb(num, scale)`
- if the number was signed, add the sign back in.

Comment: Can you help me to clarify by using an actual number like 10.5, I don't need the code btw.

Comment: @reversiblean read 10.5 as 105 in octal and divide by 8 as there is one digit after the decimal point. i.e. 69/8

Comment: But 105 / 8^1 would not get the correct answer for 10.5 in decimal. Right?

Comment: @reversiblean 105 in octal = 69 in decimal.

Comment: Oops, now I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: May I ask where did you find such simple logic? Cos I want to convert hexa decimal fractions to decimal as well?

Comment: @reversiblean I worked this out myself when I was 14 (30 years ago) so I don't know of any references on how to do it.  It's pretty trivial. One line of code and a loop for integers.